# Is it possibile change date format in Piwik?

Tags: matomo

is there a way to show another format date in piwik dashboard ? For example like this dd-mm-YYYY ? Thanks and excuse for my english.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to modify it. We might allow you to do it in the future (or even use the default date format for you language setting).

Feel free to add a new ticket to http://dev.piwik.org to request this feature.

Disclosure: I'm a Piwik dev.